# What view is the repeats in Android alarm clock?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-view

I am getting started on making an alarm clock, and I am currently working on the activity that will show an alarm's information such as the time, ringtone, and when it repeats. I am basing the design off of the stock alarm I have on my phone.
[image]

I have two questions about this design. What type of view is the repeat (those circles that represent the days)? Are all those rows (repeat, ringtone, etc.) in a list view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circular views are most likey `TextViews` with a circular drawable for the background

If I had to guess, I would say the rows are held inside a vertical `LinearLayout`, rather than a `ListView`. If vertical scrolling is required (can't tell from screenshot), then that `LinearLayout` would potentially be held inside a `ScrollView`.

You can find out exactly what is being used in the source code. I have gone to the trouble of digging up the links for you:

[XML](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/master/res/layout/alarm_time_expanded.xml#64) +
[Java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/master/src/com/android/deskclock/alarms/dataadapter/ExpandedAlarmViewHolder.java#93)